# RSA server certificate apache2

Tags: ssl, docker, https, apache2

I'm struggling at configuring vhosts with ssl certificate inside of a docker container (I don't think the problem as something to do with docker), when I connect to my site I don't have any errors, just a blank page, but in the error log I have this :

```
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:58.030690 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 754] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:58.030862 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 754] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

This is the command I type to create my key certificate :

```
sudo openssl req ­-x509 ­-nodes -­days 365 -­newkey rsa:2048 ­-out /etc/ssl/certs/mykey.crt -­keyout /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key
```

I tested to create two certificate because I need two vhosts, but it still doesn't work, here is my vhost :
        
                ServerName mysite.local

```
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

            SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "devDocker"

        <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Location /protected/>
            AuthTokenSecret       "mySuperSecret"
            AuthTokenPrefix       /protected/
            AuthTokenTimeout      120
        </Location>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-scco.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-scco.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName mysite.local

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

            SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "devDocker"
        <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Location /protected/>
            AuthTokenSecret       "mySuperSecret"
            AuthTokenPrefix       /protected/
            AuthTokenTimeout      120
        </Location>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-scco.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-scco.log combined
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mykey.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName devadmin.mysite.local

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

            SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "devDocker"

        <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Location /protected/>
            AuthTokenSecret       "mySuperSecret"
            AuthTokenPrefix       /protected/
            AuthTokenTimeout      120
        </Location>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-scco.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-scco.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName devadmin.mysite.local

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

            SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "devDocker"
            SetEnv APPLICATION_WEB_BOOTSTRAP "devadmin"
        <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Location /protected/>
            AuthTokenSecret       "mySuperSecret"
            AuthTokenPrefix       /protected/
            AuthTokenTimeout      120
        </Location>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-scco.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-scco.log combined
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mykey.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key
    </VirtualHost>
```

Here is the log I have when I type `service apache2 restart` :

```
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:56.950457 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 711] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:57.987280 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 753] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:57.987801 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 753] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:58.030501 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 754] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:58.030933 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 754] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:58.033677 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 754] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Aug 02 09:57:58.033700 2016] [core:notice] [pid 754] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It has been a while since i sat with openssl, so you will probably get better answers soon. But to help on your way until then i would guess the problem is as it say: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate. I would take that as the certificate you are trying to use on the server is actually a CA certificate and should be used to sign the certificate you should then use on the server. Some info: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an ignorable warning you'll get with self-signed certificates.